# Why Apache IoTDB reported "cannot be cast to class" error and how to solve it?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I used "createAlignedTimeseries" in Apache IoTDB, and this error was reported:
org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 305: class org.apache.ratis.protocol.Message$1 cannot be cast to class org.apache.iotdb.consensus.ratis.ResponseMessage (org.apache.ratis.protocol.Message$1 and org.apache.iotdb.consensus.ratis.ResponseMessage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

The creation of time series was successful, and it is without any tags and attributes. Anyone know what may be the reason for this error?